# How many CPU cores does a Heroku Dyno have?

Tags: heroku, cpu, celery, cpu-cores

I'm using Django with Celery 3.0.17 and now trying to figure out how many celery workers are run by default.

From [this link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-concurrency) I understand that (not having modified this config) the number of workers must be currently equal to the number of CPU cores. And that's why I need the former. I wasn't able to find an official answer by googling or searching [Heroku's dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos). I think it's 4 cores as I'm seeing 4 concurrent connections to my AMQP server, but I wanted to confirm that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The number of CPUs is not published and is subject to change, but you can find out at runtime by running `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: when I run `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo` in my 1x heroku dynos, the result is `4`

Comment: For me it was 8 on X1 dyno

Comment: As of current date, I get 8 for Standard-1X, 8 for Standard-2X, 2 for Performance-M, and 8 for Performance-L.

Comment: If anyone is not sure with the command, it's `heroku run grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo` :)

Answer (score 15):

According to https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/2/3/heroku-xl

> ```
> |       | 1X Dyno      | Performance Dyno  |
> |-------|--------------|-------------------|
> | RAM   | 512 MB       | 6 GB              |
> |       | 1x - 4x      | 40x (8 CPU cores) |
> | Price | $0.05 / hour | $0.80 / hour      |
> ```

The 2X dynos also have 4 cores:

```
$ heroku run --size=2X grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo --app app-name
Running grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo on app-name... up, run.3685
4
```

But the PX dynos have 8 cores:

```
$ heroku run --size=PX grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo --app app-name
Running grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo on app-name... up, run.4731
8
```

Comment: This answer is now very outdated. Runing the same cpuinfo test against the 4 current dyno types gives you: Standard-1x: 8 Standard-2x: 8 Performance-M: 2 Performance-L: 8

Answer (score 5):

The [heroku puma documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#process-count-value) suggests that you can find this out by running `nproc` on a dyno:

So, for example, to see how many are on performance-m, running:

```
$ heroku run bash --size=performance-l
$ nproc
8
```

But then **dividing by 2**, because:

> The value returned by nproc includes “hyperthreads” in addition to physical cores, the combination of these two are refered to as the vCPU count. All physical cores used on Heroku have a hyperthread so to gain the “true” number of physical cores divide by two.

Which would mean `performance-l` has 4 CPUs.

When I do the same on `performance-m`, I get 2, meaning actually only 1 CPU.

Standard-1x and Standard-2x both have `nproc` tell me "8", meaning 4 CPUs, but the heroku puma documentation warns that these CPUs are **shared with other users** since standard dynos are multi-tenant.

> The value for nproc from free, hobby, standard-1x, and standard-2x dynos are correct, but these cores are shared between multiple applications running in containers. While nproc for these dynos will all return 8, it is best to assume only one process can execute at a time.

Comment: Im confused why PerformanceM is returning 2...... and if i further divide by 2 that gives me 1??