# Celery immediately exceeds memory on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I'm deploying a Celery process to Heroku and every time it starts, it immediately starts to rack up memory usage and crash after it exceeds the maximum.

I only have one task called "test_task" that prints once per minute.

This is Django app using Celery with a Redis backend hosted on Heroku.

Proc file:

```
web: daphne chatbot.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 --verbosity 1
chatworker: python manage.py runworker --verbosity 1
celeryworker: celery -A chatbot worker -l info
```

Heroku logs:

```
app[celeryworker.1]: [INFO] 2018-09-11 23:06:36,710 : Scheduling celery jobs...
app[celeryworker.1]: [INFO] 2018-09-11 23:06:36,880 : adding minute task
app[celeryworker.1]: 
app[celeryworker.1]: -------------- celery@f46a12fb-1666-449a-b287-2ce90f95cf2c v4.2.0 (windowlicker)
app[celeryworker.1]: --- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-1027-aws-x86_64-with-debian-jessie-sid 2018-09-11 23:06:37
app[celeryworker.1]: -- * - **** ---
app[celeryworker.1]: ---- **** -----
app[celeryworker.1]: - ** ---------- [config]
app[celeryworker.1]: - ** ---------- .> app:         chatbot:0x7f1c2a5ad5d0
app[celeryworker.1]: - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://east-1-4.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:13275//
app[celeryworker.1]: - ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
app[celeryworker.1]: - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
app[celeryworker.1]: -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
app[celeryworker.1]: --- ***** -----
app[celeryworker.1]: -------------- [queues]
app[celeryworker.1]: .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
app[celeryworker.1]: 
app[celeryworker.1]: 
app[celeryworker.1]: [tasks]
app[celeryworker.1]: . companies.tasks.test_task
app[celeryworker.1]: 
heroku[celeryworker.1]: Process running mem=616M(120.4%)
heroku[celeryworker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
app[api]: Build succeeded
app[celeryworker.1]: [2018-09-11 23:06:55,033: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://rediscloud:**@redis-13275.c12.us-east-1-4.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:13275//
app[celeryworker.1]: [2018-09-11 23:06:55,201: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
app[celeryworker.1]: [2018-09-11 23:06:56,462: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
heroku[celeryworker.1]: Process running mem=1063M(207.8%)
heroku[celeryworker.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
heroku[celeryworker.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
heroku[celeryworker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
heroku[celeryworker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[celeryworker.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24):

Turns out changing the --concurrency argument in the celery worker process to a lower number worked.

I set it to `celery -A chatbot worker -l info --concurrency 2` and it seems to be working!

Comment: although a solution, I would love to have more context and explanation about this and to properly understand how heroku + celeris + redis work. Feels like a blackbox to me

Comment: This happened to me and reducing the concurrency to 2 worked. I suspect that the hobby dynos have 4 processors (or cores, im not sure). But the hobby plan only gives you access to one of them. But when celery starts it creates a process per processor (concurrency) and this explodes your ram usage for some reason since youre using more more resources then you have. By reducing the concurrency you consume less and you stop getting the R14.

Comment: This solved my R14 errors too

Comment: Using a basic heroku dyno i recently started getting R14's again. I lowered concurrency to 1 and am now fine again. If it starts happening again, i will try adding a second worker dyno.

Comment: This fixed my error on Render too.